# Laravel - belongsToMany getting all records, not ::find(1)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I trying to create relation between some tables in DB, so I do:
**Accreditation:**
[image]
*Model*

```
public function access() {
        return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\Sections' );
}
```

**AccreditationAccess:**
[image]
*Model*

```
public function acreditation() {
    return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\Accreditations' );
}
public function section() {
    return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\Sections' );
}
```

**Sections:**
[image]
*Model*

```
public function access() {
    return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\Accreditations' );
}
```

Now I want to display accreditation with section so I do:

```
App\Accreditations::find(1)->with('access')->get();
```

but I getting all accreditations without sections - why?

Comment: App\Accrediations::find(1)->with('access','sections')->get()

Comment: App\Accrediations::find(1)->with('access.sections')->get()

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
App\Accrediations::with('access.section')->find(1);
```

Because `->with('access')->get();`returns collection of Accrediations with `access` relations.